# Rotate Custom View in Mac OSX project

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, core-animation

I have to rotate a custom view in mac project.How can i achieve it.[image]

what i need to do when touch images it should rotate from left to right.Images are on custom view any advise would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see examples for NSView: http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-do-you-rotate-nsbutton-nstextfield.html